How to get sections of a GDoc written by a given user?
I'm working on a project where I want to get sections of a Google Doc that were written by a specific user, or alternatively get sections of the doc with author data annotated somehow.
I searched through the Google APIs for docs and didn't see anything that looked like it could obviously do this - though it looks like it would be possible to build it using the History API and a bunch of diff'ing.
Does anyone know of an existing API from Google which supports this? Or a library (Python, ideally) that would make this easier?

Hi and welcome. The goal of StackOverflow is to help users solve their problems, but it is not a free coding service. You have to decide whether your problem is your lack of coding skills, in which case you need to work on that, OR whether your problem is that the code that you have written or researched is not meeting your needs. In both cases, I think you have some work to do, and you can edit your question when you have a more specific problem to resolve.
